# What is the recommended Hotkey for an 'Apply'-Button

Tags: user-interface, usability

An Apply button is in many systems and programs, a common approach, which has its place (look and feel). But what is the recommended Hotkey for an 'Apply'-Button.

OK(Enter), Cancel(ECS), Help(F1), Apply(??)

Which Hotkey do you prefer?

Comment: »prefer« leans towards subjective. I guess you would want to ask something subtly different ;-) (at least since you're probably not writing software for any of us out opinion of what we prefer in this matter should be meaningless).

Comment: for sure, there is a "subjectiveness" in our perceptions, but all of us have similar eyes and a similar way of abstract things in our brain. Therefore, usability is not subjective and the question is legitimate.

Comment: My recommendation is not to use one. If users want keyboard access they can press ALT and use an accelerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, I'd say. So simply use the normal accelerators (those prefixed with `&`).

As far as I know there are no default single-key accelerators in dialogs beyond those you mentioned already.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you not to force the user to apply something. Try to apply the users input directly. This simplyfies your application because the user does not have to care about this. Anyway you have to give the user a feedback for his changes. Show him a "your input was saved" message (no message box). Try to avoid every step which is not needed. This makes your application or webpage more userfriendly.

Besides this, no user wants to remember "hotkeys" for thousands of programs.

Comment: Immediate apply violates the rule of safe discovering.

Comment: Undo can solve it, but it depends on the subject of the software.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a hotkey, then I recommend some ENTER like combination.
We can look the Apply as a semi OK, because the modifications are commited but the window stay open.
A semi ENTER can be for example a CTRL+ENTER or CTRL+ALT+ENTER, etc